# ScrollView contendo RelativeLayout

Tags: android

Quando coloco meu App em modo paisagem, ele corta uma parte das informações. Então preciso colocar um `ScrollView`. Porém, já busquei em vários sites e até na documentação mas mesmo assim não consigo fazer ele funcionar. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cabecalho"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#0097A7"
            android:fontFamily="cursive"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="Pousada George's Village"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold|italic"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/georges"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/local"
            android:layout_below="@id/cabecalho"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/georges"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/local"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:padding="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/local"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/fone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/local"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/telefone"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/site"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/fone"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/site"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/site"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:src="@drawable/email"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/localizacao"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/georges"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/local"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:text="Av. Ver. Manoel dos Santos, 195 - Centro, Bombinhas - SC, 88215-000."
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texto_fone"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/local"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/fone"
            android:text="(47) 3369-2177."
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texto_site"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/fone"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/site"
            android:text="https://www.georgesvillage.com.br"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texto_email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/site"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/email"
            android:text="reservas@georgesvillage.com.br"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texto_hotel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/email"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:text="Este hotel informal com vista para o Oceano Atlântico está distribuído em vários prédios cercados por florestas tropicais, fica a 6 minutos a pé da Praia de Bombinhas e a 19 km da rodovia federal BR-101."
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:textColor="#000000"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/texto_hotel"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:padding="5dp"
            android:text="By: R.A.O."
            android:textSize="7sp"
            android:textStyle="italic"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Bem-vindo à comunidade Rogério. Veja se essa resposta ajuda: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18677515/8133067

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza o `NestedScrollView`, como o nome sugere é usado quando há necessidade de uma exibição de rolagem dentro de outra exibição de rolagem. Normalmente, isso seria difícil de realizar, já que o sistema não poderia decidir qual visualização deveria ser rolada. É aqui que entra o NestedScrollView, ou seja, ele so exibe a rolagem quando necessita..

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/nested_scroll_text"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```